# Interpreter is showing "list indices must be integers, not str" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python. I have combined  numbers and letters in one list. Next I wanted to choose only numbers and append them to another list. When the program encounters letters it gives me this error:

> if not str(a[x]).isalpha(): TypeError: list indices must be integers,
>   not str

```
a = []
b = 'This is a dog'
d = [888, 999]
c = []

for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)

a.extend(b)
for elem in d:
    a.append(elem)

print(a)
print('---------------------------------')
for x in a:
    if not str(a[x]).isalpha():
        c.append(a[x])
        print(c)
    else:
        pass

print(c)
```

I will appreciate if you can teach me in this case.

Comment: A list in Python is just an array.  It is a sequence of values which can be referenced by their position within the list, which is their index.  The first element has index 0, the second has index 1, etc.  For this data structure, an index that is not an integer makes no sense.  If you wish to look up values by a key, then you can use a dict.

Comment: because it is an index. it has to be an ordinal number.

Comment: x refers to the elements in a, not to the index. If you want to iterate using key and value, you need to use enumerate: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: If you want to index by `str` use a `dict`. Or if you want to access indices of a list while iterating, use `enumerate`. It returns `(index, item)`

Comment: Thank you for all response! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('---------------------------------')
for x in a: # Here you'll get each value of a in x.
    if not str(x).isalpha(): # So here you don't have to use a[x] but simply x.
        c.append(x)
        print(c)
    else:
        pass
```

What you are doing fails because at some point in `x` you have "This is a dog".
Asking for `a[x]` then means asking python to look for "this is a dog" as an index in `a`.
This fails and python tells you that lists only have integer indices, not strings.

Comment: You have right. I changed isalpha() to isnumeric(), becouse isalpha() gives me blank spaces

Answer (score 2):

Just as commented by some, the concept of `list` is like an `array`. It is *ordered* and thus is accessed by index, which is integer.

Just imagine if you have a row of rooms in a hotel or houses in the same street. It just makes sense if the houses or rooms are numbered to show that the objects are ordered. This goes the same for memory location for `list`. Thus, it is to be accessed by `int`.

However, it is quite different case when you deal with, say, dictionary. The concept is not that it must be ordered in a row, but as long as you have a `key`, you should be able to get the correct `value` for the key. This is, probably, more like how our brain works when we translate one language to another. As long as we have the word from one language (key) we could get the right translated word (value) in the other language (such as "centre" is English is translated to "Zhong" in Chinese). Thus the term `dictionary` is not too far off the reality (albeit in our dictionary book the words are usually ordered by alphabets, but we don't use it by number - but rather by searching the word we want to translate).

Now to answer your programming question, when you do `for x in a` you already get element of `a` one by one. You only need to check if `not str(x).isalpha` instead of accessing it by `a[x]`:

```
print(a)
print('---------------------------------')
for x in a:
    if not str(x).isalpha(): #use x directly, x represents an element in a already
        c.append(x)
        print(c)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Mao you are welcome. :) I try to put some explanation to help you make sense of the concepts. :)

Answer (score 0):

You see, python expression like "for x in a" where a is a list already gives you elements of that list, so no need for a[x].

This should work:

```
for x in a:
    if not str(x).isalpha():
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for so much help. The code below is what I wanted to do.

```
a = []
b = 'This is a dog'
d = [888, 999]
c = []

for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)

a.extend(b)
for elem in d:
    a.append(elem)

print(a)
print('---------------------------------')
for x in a:
    if str(x).isnumeric():
        c.append(x)
        print(c)
    else:
        pass

print(c)
```